# Probability: Finding the number of trials to get a certain percentage.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

My assignment is to find the number of trials in order to get a probability greater of 95% given that each success is 25%. My first thought was to use Binomial Distribution:
$$
\ P(X>=n) = 1 - nC0*p^(0)(1-p)^(n)
\\
\ .95 >= 1 - (1-.25)^(n)
\\
\ 1-.95 <=(1-.25)^(n)
\\
\ n >= log(1-.95)/log(1-.25)
$$

I got that n >= 11 trials are needed to get a percentage greater than 95%

Comment: What exactly is the question you are asking?

Comment: Assume that overtime you conduct an experiment you have a 25% chance of success. How many trials must you conduct so that the probability of getting a successful experiment is greater than 95%

Comment: We want the probability of all failures to be $\lt 0.05$.The probability of all failures in $n$ trials is $(0.75)^n$. We want this to be $\lt 0.05$. Your calculation that leads to the conclusion the smallest $n$ that qualifies is $11$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a random variable $X \sim B(n, 0.25)$ and you want to find the smallest value of $n$ such that $P(X \geq 1) \geq 0.95$.

Because the binomial distribution is descrete, $P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P (X < 1) = 1 - P(X = 0)$. So you're looking for the smallest value of $n$ such that $1 - P(X = 0) \geq 0.95$.

For any binomially distributed variable, $P(X = 0) = (1 - p) ^ n$.

So this gives you $1 - (1 - (0.25)) ^ n \geq 0.95$. Solve for n and round up to the nearest integer (giving 11, so you were correct).